# PHP generating 13-digit timestamp like mktime

Tags: php, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php get microtime from date string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289160/php-get-microtime-from-date-string)

For a specific purpose, I need to get the 13-digit timestamp for a date/time, but I couldn't find a solution for this.

Like **mktime** in PHP, we can get a 10-digit timestamp

```
echo mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year);
```

This outputs something like 1346689283.

So what about the 13-digit timestamp? Is PHP itself capable of generating such timestamps?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for `microtime()`

http://php.net/microtime

If you want to create microtime from a specific date, just add `000`. Because in the end, the microtime is only 1 second.

Comment: yes, but I think he wants something that can create microtime from arbitrary dates, like mktime or strtotime would allow for unix timestamps

Comment: @gordon well added that to the answer

Comment: yep, Gordon's right, microtime() generates CURRENT timestamp with microseconds, and it will not allow me to specify year/month/day/hour/... Example: I need to get the 13-digit timestamp for 1998-02-13 17:44

Comment: But there are no microseconds in "1998-02-13 17:44"? You might as well add '000' like Rene Pot said.

Comment: @user1643156 the microseconds are 1 second. Do you need it so specific? You can add any 3 random numbers like you want. It is not gonna make a big difference anyways.

Comment: @Rene Pot, by adding 000 seems not working (maybe just in the program I'm using), it results a 1970 error. but 001 - 999 they all work. Anyway, why didn't I just try adding 3 numbers before posting... :) thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Make milliseconds:

```
$milliseconds = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
echo date("Y-m-d",($milliseconds/1000));
```