# PHP - Convert specific hour into microtime

Tags: php, microtime

I need to know how to convert 07:00pm of the current date in microtime. Sorry if this is a silly question but I cannot find the answer anywhere

Comment: nothing in the manual? http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php saw a few.

Comment: @Fred-ii- where? I cannot see the solution to my problem there

Comment: this `$micro_date = microtime();
$date_array = explode(" ",$micro_date);
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$date_array[1]);
echo "Date: $date:" . $date_array[0];` seemed promising.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry but I don't see how that is related. I need something like strtotime(date("Y-m-d 19:00:00")); but this is not working.

Comment: I said it "seemed promising" ;-) of course you'd have to add a few ingredients to the soup. See the answers you've been given.

Comment: check out this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289160/php-get-microtime-from-date-string

Comment: Not a silly question, but not very well explained. Try again, maybe with an example of what you are actually trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[php mktime()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mktime.php)

```
//set timezone to default
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
//this will give you the timestamp of today, 7:00:00 pm (which is 19 o' clock in 24hour system
$time = mktime(19,0,0);
```

you then can format the timestamp to whatever kind of format you need.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making a `DateTime` object, then formatting it into unix time?

```
$dt = new DateTime('7:00pm');
echo $dt->format('U');
```

There are obviously more efficient ways to do it if you're not dealing with a string to begin with.